# odf files for arkandis fonts lack features in tex definitions

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

The [Arkandis Digital Foundry](https://arkandis.tuxfamily.org/index.html) publishes a variety of comprehensive font families, apparently expressing high artistic merit, under an open license.

Support in LaTeX through external packages has been submitted into CTAN.

For example, the [`venturisadf`](https://ctan.org/pkg/venturisadf) package has integrated the *Venturis* font family.

From the  [documentation](http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/fonts/venturisadf/doc/fonts/venturisadf/venturisadf.pdf) for the CTAN package:

> …condensed and standard-width Venturis regular and bold provide a choice of oldstyle and lining figures, upright and italic small capitals and alternate swash characters while the regular upright face also offers end-of-word swashes. All of these features are accessible in LaTeX through the included package files…

The same document shows examples of these features, including small capitals.

The CTAN index suggests, apparently incorrectly, that the package contains OTF representations of the fonts.

The greater discrepancy, however, is that the OTF representations available for general use [directly from the foundry](https://arkandis.tuxfamily.org/tugfonts.htm) appear not to contain the `smcp` feature, as revealed by inspection through `otfinfo -f`.  Indeed, when these files are used in XeLaTeX through the `fontspec` package, the small capitals are not displayed in blocks formatted using `\scshape`, and the engine warns about the appearance of the command.

The discrepancy is partly but inadequately resolved by a note, on the foundry’s site, seeming to indicate that most collections currently lack small-capital glyphs.

If the small-capital glyphs are seen in the LaTeX package, then the font collections must include them, and ideally general applications using OTF, including XeLaTeX, can use them.

From where are the small-capital glyphs being taken for the TeX font definitions?  Can the glyphs also be used with the OTF files?  If not, why?

Comment: The small caps available with pdflatex seem indeed to be true small caps and not just scaled down capitals. I can't say what the source is, though.

Comment: @egreg I can confirm that all Arkandis packages provided by me (including venturisadf) include only true small caps. The font designer does not support faked small caps and did not want TeX support packages to offer them. I support and respect this decision. If small caps are not available, an alternative shape is substituted (e.g. upright).

Comment: In my packages, the small-caps glyphs and metrics are taken from the fonts from the foundry. There's nothing mysterious going on here.

Comment: @cfr Ok, great, but it's mysterious to me because I can't find them.  The OTF files don't show the `smcp` feature and XeLaTeX doesn't find the glyphs from those files. So my question seems to be how I, or the application, can find and use those glyphs.

Comment: @cfr On the author's site, first link in the post.  Most of the fonts are found by following the menu *Fonts / ADF Fonts*. However, the fonts in this example (*Venturis*) are under *Fonts / TUG Fonts*, with the distribution file accessible from the ZIP icon on the right. ([*Direct link*](https://arkandis.tuxfamily.org/fonts/Venturis-Serie-20100704.zip), in case needed.)

Comment: Thanks. I was confused and thought it linked to CTAN, but I see that's the next link over. The glyphs and metrics will all be there in the OTF fonts, but they are dispersed among different fonts, rather than enabled as features. You can workaround this for small-caps, but I doubt you can get end-of-word swashes and things to work the way I have in the LaTeX package. If you want to use these fonts, I suggest using the package with the type1 files. I don't see any reason to use the OTF in this case.

Comment: One reason to prefer OTF is that it has superseded Type1 and is better supported by modern software. E.g. do browsers support Type1? Are you saying that the author created glyphs for swashes and other features but didn't fully encode them in the published OTF files?

Comment: The OTF are setup to reflect what I'd consider something closer to a traditional postscript type1 layout. This means the glyphs and metrics are split between different fonts. (They aren't laid out quite like this, but the layout is much closer that that than it is to the way a modern opentype font might be constructed.)

Comment: They're encoded in the OTF files, but they aren't available as opentype features. The glyphs and metrics are there in both type1 and opentype fonts. They are, informationally, equivalent as far as I know. (Possibly the type1 might have fewer kerning pairs. I can't remember even if I did the conversion. i think not for `venturisadf`. Possibly even the conversion went the other way, as the file layout suggests.) Sometimes you lose information converting to type1 because the format is more limited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LaTeX support packages authored by me include small-caps if, and only if, small-caps were available in the fonts at the time the packages were created.

[venturisadf](https://ctan.org/pkg/venturisadf) is a complicated case, because some glyphs are taken from different fonts roughly in accordance with the stated intentions of the fonts' designer. In essence, the LaTeX package provides three sets of font families. These do not map perfectly to the original designer's intentions, but I did my best to approximate those intentions as closely as possibly.

Generally speaking 'titling' fonts contain small-caps intended to complement the non-small-caps fonts. In order to make all this work seamlessly in LaTeX, the package defines a set of families, drawing glyphs and metrics from the appropriate underlying fonts. These are then grouped into three sets corresponding to the three `.sty` files included in the package. Some have small-caps (where there are small-caps intended to work with the base fonts) and some do not (where there aren't.)

To get this working with (pdf)LaTeX, all that is required is:

1. the glyphs
2. the metrics
3. knowledge of the font designer's intentions.

The rest of the work is done by the support files.

This is an entirely separate question from the issue of whether the OTF fonts support particular features. Basically, `fontspec` makes it possible to use a full range of opentype features *if* the opentype or truetype font is set up correctly by the font designer. If not, you are (absent special gymnastics) out of luck.

A traditional font support package can do more with less. I don't need font tables or features to be configured correctly to provide a package supporting end-of-word swashes or italic small-caps or whatever. I just need the glyphs and the metrics. Nor does it matter if the end-of-word swashes are in a different font from the regular characters. This means that what you can do with the font depends less on the font designer and more on the software using the font or, in the case of LaTeX, on the author of the support package.

Hence, in one sense, `fontspec` gives you greater flexibility. But, in another, it is more rigid. If everything is there in the font, great. No package author required. If it isn't there, tough. Where you have separate opentype fonts for small-caps, say, you can use `fontspec` to specify the font to use for small-caps.  Otherwise, there's not much doing.

In the case of `venturisadf`, you can match fonts against the 'titling' families and specify those as the small-caps fonts. To find out how it is done for the LaTeX packages, look at the source files. `rename.*` shows you the mappings to Berry font names. The `*.etx`, `*-drv.tex` and `*.mtx` files show you how the characters from the raw fonts are encoded and combined to create the font families specified in the `*.fd` files used by LaTeX. But note there's a lot of combining going on here - the final font LaTeX uses is taking glyphs and metrics from multiple type1 postscript fonts. For example, 't' may be in one font, while swash 'w' is in another, but you can still write `twin` using the swash in LaTeX and have it all work, because LaTeX uses a 'virtual font', which doesn't include any glyphs at all. This just isn't how `fontspec` works.

Comment: Trying to put it all together... the feature-system of OTF is such that fonts usually work out-of-the-box in an application, such as XeLaTeX, that has OTF support. However, the published OTF files in this case lack a layout that allows applications reliably to use all the glyphs as intended.  Nevertheless the LaTeX package is designed such that the TeX engine is able to compose dynamically a particular view of the fonts by taking various glyphs from designated definitions files. The author supported use of glyphs from the titling fonts as stand-ins for small caps in the LaTeX package.

Comment: @epl Not 'stand-ins'. Closer to these are the intended small-caps. As you may know, postscript type1 fonts traditionally had small-caps, ligatures and certain symbols in separate font files. So, traditionally, you expected to find `fi` in a different file from `f` and `i`, for example.

Comment: @epl TeX doesn't combine anything dynamically. TeX doesn't even know there are separate fonts. TeX doesn't use glyphs. It just typesets boxes. pdfTeX is different, but there's still nothing dynamic about it. The virtual fonts point to characters in the real fonts (usually - sometimes they do something else). The DVI viewer or converter or pdfTeX uses these instructions to find the glyphs (where appropriate). Nothing is done 'on-the-fly'. It is all done before hand. Some of my font packages use virtual fonts because I'd not figured out an alternative. Not so this one. Here, they're essential.

Comment: That's what I meant.  "Virtual fonts point to characters in the real fonts" = "compose dynamically a particular view of the fonts by taking various glyphs from designated definitions files".

Comment: @epl Er ... OK. You obviously use 'dynamic' to mean something different from me ;).

Comment: You're right: virtual but still static. But back to the issue, why are the OTF files not assembled to work transparently using the capabilities of the format? And looking further at the entire collection of OTF files, I still cannot find italic and non-bold small capitals, or any swash forms, all appearing in the LaTeX package. Where are they defined? I guess it was never intended that all the features of this collection be used outside of the standard TeX engines...

Comment: @epl As for the OTF files, you would have to ask their author. The characters are all there in the fonts. You can see where they come from by looking at the `-drv.tex` file in conjunction with the `rename.` and `.mtx` files. The swash forms are in the 'style' fonts, if I remember correctly. At least, most of them. `\installfont{yv1dd8tu}{t1-yv1dd-u,newlatin}{t1-f_f}{T1}{yv1d}{dbuc}{sc}{}` is telling you where small-caps in series `dbuc` comes from for family `yv1d`. You can then see that the same font is installed for a number of other series, including `m`.

Comment: @epl This used to be a much more standard setup and it was not originally designed for TeX. Rather, other applications used font layouts like this. Virtual fonts were designed partly to enable TeX to take advantage of existing postscript fonts, including those where some characters were provided in separate files. This isn't a TeX-centric font design. I never used that software, but that's they way commercial typesetting software (think Adobe) expected postscript fonts to be constructed.

Comment: I understand your observation. Reviewing the author's web site, development can be seen for new fonts more recent than the release of Venturis, despite no update to Venturis in about 9 years. Understandably, other interests take precedent over maintaining the file layout to represent the latest advances in the font-specification formats. Yet it would be wonderful if new versions were available that integrate seamlessly into modern applications, without the manual effort that has been made obsolete by such advances.

Comment: @epl I strongly disagree with the claim that manual effort has been made obsolete. I wouldn't use pdfTeX if I needed to typeset, say, Arabic, but it is my engine of choice given that I don't. In the TeX world, the new options don't make manual effort obsolete anyway. They shift it from the packager to the font designer. At some point, somebody has to do the work of connecting everything up. Whether it is in the font or in a bunch of support files, it has to be done. And traditional type1 fonts in TeX have both cons and pros. I don't deny the advantages of OTF, but everything comes at a price.

Comment: You can always email the font designer with a feature request or ask whether the foundry would welcome updated versions, if you were to make them. @epl

Comment: Using the newer features of the font formats, the author packages information into the font specification file about how the font functions, which is used automatically and consistently by any application that uses that format, whether a TeX engine or another. No one would contend that this information is not created by someone, only that *from a user standpoint* the file is sufficient to plug into an application such that it works correctly, as the author intends, without work or understanding. Such was the intended meaning of my comment.

Comment: @epl *From a user perspective* the same is true of a font package, except that the packager may not package the font in a way which reflects the author's intentions. Generally, that is probably a disadvantage in theory. Whether it is generally a disadvantage in practice is another question. But I'm really not trying to deny the advantages you're claiming. They are advantages. But the traditional setup has advantages, too. Mostly, though, I'm objecting to the claim this stuff is 'obsolete'. That's just not true.

Comment: My use of the term *obsolete*, admittedly a strong word, was based on an understanding that the newer features of the font formats were intended to supersede application-specific solutions like LaTeX packages by offering the same capabilities with better portability. Perhaps I neglected to consider advantages of the earlier solutions, but I don't recall that any were mentioned in this discourse, except that they were formally the only available kind of solution.

Comment: @epl Working with pdfTeX is an *enormous* advantage for many of us. It is the most stable, widely available and reliable engine which outputs a modern format (i.e. PDF rather than DVI) and is compatible with inclusion of a wide range of image formats, Ti*k*Z etc. One day, LuaTeX may supersede it, but not yet. Not by a long way. The other advantage of traditional font formats is that the support can be tailor-made for LaTeX. That costs in terms of portability, but it sometimes gains in terms of ease of use. + virtual fonts make it possible to combine characters from different fonts as one.

Comment: *The other advantage of traditional font formats is that the support can be tailor-made for LaTeX.*  I understand the statement, but fail to understand how fonts tailor-made for LaTeX, practically, is an advantageous, as long as the capabilities historically limited to TeX processors are now standard features in font formats and display and publishing environments. Meanwhile, if pdfTeX is not needed for these capabilities (I realize you say it is), then is there any remaining sense in which XeTeX (or LuaTeX) would not effectively supersede pdfTeX?

Comment: @epl pdfTeX is still the go-to engine *despite* reliance on traditional font formats - not because of it. It is far more stable, for one thing. (The newer engines are pretty stable, but I wouldn't use them for everyday work unless I couldn't live without the new font capabilities, which I can.) Mathematical typesetting with opentype fonts is in its infancy, as far as I'm concerned, though that's not my reason for sticking to pdfTeX for production.

Comment: I accept that history, convention, and stability, especially for mathematical typesetting, weigh in favor of the older-style engines. I wasn't focused on these issues, though naturally they are too important to ignore.